# How to change navigator initial route after login react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm new in react native and currently developing a react-native app that require login. After successful login, the view change into Homepage. The problem is after i close and re-open the app, it shows me LoginPage again. 
Normally when you close some app that require login and re-open it, it will redirect to home page if you're already login. but in my case, it always show the LoginPage first.

How to change initial route to HomePage if the user already login when close and re-open the app?

Here's some code what i've done:

```js
class Main extends Component {
  
  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
      if (route.id === 1) {
        return <LoginPage navigator={navigator} />
      } else if (route.id === 2) {
        return <HomePage navigator={navigator} />
      } else if (route.id === 3) {
        return <DetailPage navigator={navigator} />
      }  else if (route.id === 4) {
        return <CreateBookingPage navigator={navigator} />
      }
  }

  _configureScene(route) {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
  }
  
  
  render() {
      return (
        <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }} />
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store if a user is logged in or not.

Comment: Actually it knows that user is loggin because touch login button for the second time after successful login (with empty textinput) it redirect to homepage. The problem is whenever i close and re-open the app it always show the LoginPage, not redirect to homePage.

Comment: Can't you simply implement an if statement in your Login Activity in the onResume() method - if the user is logged in --> open next Activity. But I don't know if the user can see the animation.

Comment: I'm sorry i think you misunderstanding with my question. The app can open next activity to homepage and so on after login. Normally when you close some app that require login and re-open it, it will redirect to home page if you're already login. but in my case, it always show the LoginPage first, not directly to homepage.

Comment: I understood that, I'm sorry if I expressed myself wrong, english is not my native language. When you close your app, save a flag in the Shared Preferences that the user logged in before (not in the login activity, in any other). In the **onResume()** method in your LoginActivity, get the info from the SharedPreferences and stay on the Activity or get to the next one. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

check your manifest file for

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

set it into homepage activity, you can save username in shared  Shared Preferences 
and  and check condition over there if you are getting username as null then pass intent for loginpage